# Getting access to a database variable

Tags: php

I'd like to pull a value from my database and use it as the current page title. My connection works, the page loads fine, but I need access to a variable and I can't figure this one out.

How my page is structured:

Blog.php

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/header.php');
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $blogid = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, title, slug, body, image, author, date, category from blog WHERE id= :id ORDER BY date DESC");
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $_GET['id']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
}

if(isset($row['title'])) {
    $pageTitle = $row['title'];
} else {
    $pageTitle = "Something Here";
}
```

`$pageTitle` is a variable in `$header.php`. It controls the `<title>` tage for each page.

Problem

My database connection `$dbh` is set in `header.php`. this means I don't have access to `$row['title']` until it's too late.

Question:

How can I restructure this to gain access to `$row['title']` BEFORE `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/header.php');`. I really don't want to pull the database connection out of the header if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Comment: So in your current structure, you can't put anything in the <head> section of the html page?

Comment: Correct. That's all set in `header.php`

Comment: Then it is not possible; you could use a javascript fix though; This, by setting a hidden value on you page (html body) and let a javascript get it for you and set it as the page title, using body onload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, because your `<title></tile>` is already printed in the ouput.
An hardcore fix would be to use rendering in buffer (with ob_start ob_get_content) then parse the rendered content to change the content of your `<title>` tag.

However the clever way is to get your database out of your header.

Regards

Comment: `However the clever way is to get your database out of your header.` I could pull it out and include it on all pages separately, but I really don't want to go through all my files and do that if I don't have to

Comment: I completly understand, it was not meant to be an harmful comment. You have in fact another solution which is to make the query for your title in the header.php script, but you will have to check which query to use for your different page. Putting your database object in a different file will be painful at the begening but you will gain a lot in flexibility.

Comment: I didn't take it as harmful. Thanks for your comments!